# How to express to a friend that someone outed their HIV status to me and that they should be aware who they share it with?

Tags: conversations, awkward-situations, lgbt+

One of my gay friends told me that another friend of ours is HIV+ and that I should therefore avoid him. I told him is HIV status doesn't matter to me and that he should never have to tell me. And even if he did, it doesn't even matter.

But it's been long and I didn't have the chance to tell him that, and also I am not sure about how reliable this information is.

So my intention is to express to my friend that even if he is HIV+ he should be careful about who he shares this information with on dating sites but also if he is not HIV positive it should not hurt him. As this guy used this information and rumour in a harmful way only.

Comment: Perhaps a nice related one to read about friends outing pretty personal (but possibly fake) info: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/24275/1599

Comment: @Tinkeringbell nice read

Comment: the more I think about this, the more I think this might be a duplicate. Is there anything (except the kind of information being shared) that makes this different from the question I linked you above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell my date that one of her close friends outed her to me as trans?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/how-can-i-tell-my-date-that-one-of-her-close-friends-outed-her-to-me-as-trans)